Global modal in react native performance question
I am working on a expo react-native mobile app that need to access foreground and background location (scope always). And I would like to add a custom popup to explain why the app need this access prior to request them.
I want to cover these cases :

The user grant access at the first start
The user does not grant access and click on a feature that require permission
The user grant access but not in the correct scope

I am wondering what would be the best place to put the modal and the permission code.
I also could put this modal into a layout wrapping my navigation stack but I do not know what's best
I've created an App-scoped context "LocationRightContext" exposing 2 methods : getLocationPermission and askLocationPermissionIfHasntRight.
The last method will check if the permission has already be granted and if not :

It will show a modal explaining the reasons of the request

On "Accept" : it will trigger the requestForegroundLocationAsync() and requestBackgroundLocationAsync() from expo-location.
On "Refuse" it will navigate back to the Home page



Is there a risk of re-render madness, memory leak ? Especially in the best case : the pop-up is used only one time in the lifetime of the app, but still existing within the context.
import * as Location from 'expo-location'
import React, { useContext, useMemo } from 'react'
import { isNil } from 'lodash'
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import { Modal } from 'react-native-paper'
import PopupLocationRequest from '../components/organisms/PopupLocationRequest'

const LocationRightContext = React.createContext()

function LocationRightContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [locationRequested, setLocationRequested] = React.useState(false)
  const handleExitModal = () => {
    setLocationRequested(false)
  }
  /**
   * Request foreground and background location status
   */
  const askLocationPermission = async () => {
    // const { android: forePermissionAndroid, ios: forePermissionIos } =
    //   await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
    await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
    await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync()
    setLocationRequested(false)
  }

  /**
   * Get foreground and background location status
   */
  const getLocationPermission = async () => {
    const foregroundPermission = await Location.getForegroundPermissionsAsync()
    const backgroundPermission = await Location.getBackgroundPermissionsAsync()
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return (
        !isNil(foregroundPermission) &&
        foregroundPermission.ios.scope === 'always' &&
        !isNil(backgroundPermission) &&
        backgroundPermission.status === 'granted'
      )
    }
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      return (
        !isNil(foregroundPermission.android) &&
        foregroundPermission.android.accuracy !== 'none' &&
        !isNil(backgroundPermission) &&
        backgroundPermission.status === 'granted'
      )
    }
    return false
  }

  /**
   * Display information modal if location has not been granted
   */
  const askLocationPermissionIfHasntRight = async () => {
    if (!(await getLocationPermission())) {
      setLocationRequested(true)
    }
    return true
  }

  const value = useMemo(
    () => ({
      getLocationPermission,
      askLocationPermissionIfHasntRight,
    }),
    [getLocationPermission, askLocationPermissionIfHasntRight],
  )
  return (
    <LocationRightContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
      <Modal
        visible={locationRequested}
        dismissable
        onDismiss={handleExitModal}
      >
        <PopupLocationRequest
          callbackOnAccept={askLocationPermission}
          callbackOnDeny={handleExitModal}
        />
      </Modal>
    </LocationRightContext.Provider>
  )
}

const useLocationRightContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(LocationRightContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      'useLocationContext must be used within a LocationRightContextProvider',
    )
  }
  return context
}

export {
  LocationRightContextProvider,
  useLocationRightContext,
  LocationRightContext,
}


